# KAFKA connect EOFException when running connect-standalone with confluent broker and source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i am trying to run a connect-standalone application with a sample soure connector. (FileSource or JDBC connector).
i am getting constantly repeating error messages like

```
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,641] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Connection with xxxx.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud/ (channelId=-1) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector:606)
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:328)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,643] INFO [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:935)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,645] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 34ms, elapsed time since send: 34ms, request timeout: 30000ms): ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.2.1') (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:335)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,647] WARN [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Bootstrap broker xxxx.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1063)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,757] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Initialize connection to node xxxx.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1160)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,758] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] Resolved host xxxx.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud as  (org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils:113)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,758] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Initiating connection to node xxxx.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address xxxx.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud/ (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:989)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,787] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector:531)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,788] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:951)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,789] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:965)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,789] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0, correlationId=1) and timeout 30000 to node -1: ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.2.1') (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:521)
[2022-11-14 18:33:09,817] DEBUG [local-file-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-local-file-source-0] Connection with xxxx.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud/ (channelId=-1) disconnected
```

I can create a topic with the kafka-topics.sh command, write messages through the console producer to the topic and read from the topic through console consumer as well as with connect-standalone with sink connectors.

If i am running kafka server and zookeper locally everything seems to work fine.

commandline:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties
```

connect-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=pkc-pj9zy.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="name" password="passphrase";
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
plugin.path=./plugins,./libs
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

connect-file-source.properties

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=test.txt
topic=test_ksql_af_file_source-test
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
```

Comment: Please show your `connect-standalone.properties`... If it works with sink connectors, then you know you can pass multiple properties files to `connect-standalone`? You don't need to stop/start to run independent connectors.

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted out.

was missing the properties

```
producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
producer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="name" password="passphrase";
```

in my settings.

The log did unfortunately not give a hint about this